# FB Like button on webpage shows different count than the like count on FB page.

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a FB Page for our site that has a decent count of 'Likes'.

Now, we added the Like button to our website which shows the number of Likes. The problem is that the number in the Like button on my site is much less than the actual number of likes on the FB page. Even the likes in the facebook graph are smaller than the page likes. Obviously some likes are missing or not getting counted. I tried Linter, but no change.

I cannot find anything in FB developer's help that can explain this.

Answer (score 1):

The like count you see next to the like button on the website is a count of those who have liked that page. It is not related to the number of likes of your Facebook page.

Answer (score 0):

As the [Social Plugins FAQs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs?locale=en_US#faq_233117017073109) mentioned, the like count after the like button on web page includes:

- The number of likes of your URL
- The number of shares of your URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)
- The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about your URL

So it's not just as simple 'like' count on your FB page.